# Snowflake mapping columns names from CSV files

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in Snowflake that have 24 columns in it. And I also have a CSV files in the S3 bucket with the changing number of columns. Sometimes it can be 4 columns and sometimes it can be 24 columns etc. I need also map the names of the CSV files columns to the name of the Snowflake table columns. Is there any way how to do it?

Comment: Can the file type be changed? If so, you should be interested in the INFER_SCHEMA functionality: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/infer_schema.html#infer-schema
This feature is currently limited to Apache Parquet, Apache Avro, and ORC files.

Comment: Sorry but it can't be changed

Answer (score 1):

You would need to pre-process your CSV file to bring it to a more consistent format as your target table.

You can extract the column header and generate a COPY command mapping those columns into your table.